# Regex between line start and character

Tags: regex, coffeescript, syntax-highlighting, vim

I am not experienced with regexes at all. I need a simple regex for my vim script for highlighting a coffeescript function or variable.

So in the following code

```
myvar = 12
square = (x) -> x * x
```

Would highlight `myvar` and `square`

Basically anything between the beginning of the line and and and an equals sign.

Here's how I would express it in psuedocode

```
x = line.between("beginning of line", "=")

if x.contains(" ", "+", "-", "etc.")
    return false
else
    return true
```

I doesn't have to work in all cases, just something I can work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^[^=]\+\(=\)\@=`

Breakdown:

1. `^` matches the beginning of the line
2. `[^=]\+` matches one or more non-`=` characters (i.e. everything up to the first `=`)
3. `\(=\)\@=` positive lookahead that looks for the equal sign (to ensure there is one in the line) but doesn't select it

Comment: Doesn't this select all text in a line until there is a `=`? So if there is no `=` in the whole line, it selects the whole line.

Comment: Do you have other data your trying to match?

Answer (score 0):

```
^([^=]+)\=
```

is how I would do it...

Answer (score 0):

```
^\w\+\s*=
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/9yuGIIjsJYD3mKJh)

- `^` beginning of line
- `\w+` At least one word character (letter, number, underscore)
- `\s*` 0 or more spaces

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

```
^[^=]\{-1,}\ze\s*=
```

which means:

- `^` : start of line
- `[^=]\{-1,}` : any character except `=`, one or more times, but as few as possible (this means, try not to glob trailing spaces)
- `\ze` : end of match, what follows is a positive lookahead assertion (like using `\(what follows\)\@=`)
- `\s*=` : any number of spaces, and equal sign